# Azure Mobile Services - Server Side Scripts - Comparison to zero using ===

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have just started playing the Azure Mobile Services stuff.  It's super cool however there are a few weird things I have noticed while trying to change the server side database scripts.  One specific thing is that while writing a simple statement like:

if (results.length == 0)

it warned me saying that I should use === instead of == while comparing with zero.

Anyone know why  that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loosely-typed languages, it's often useful to use === (strict equality operator) rather than == (equality operator), because otherwise the types of objects will be coerced during the equality check.

For example, `"0" == 0`, and `"" == 0`, and `[] == 0`.

However, none of those `=== 0`.

So if `results` happened to be an object with an empty property `length`, like so:

```
var results = {
  length: ""
}
```

`results.length == 0` would still evaluate to `true`.

Comment: It is not true that `null == 0`.

Comment: Ah true, that's my PHP kicking in. (In PHP, null does == 0. In Javascript it does not.) Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
[] == 0
```

is true, but

```
[] === 0
```

Isn't.

Read about [JavaScript comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) (and *strict equality* in particular).